# Local-exec using powershell throws Cannot index into a null array

Tags: terraform, azure-powershell, terraform-provider-azure

Had some help in getting PowerShell command to run in Terraform local-exec [See here for code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70382971/local-exec-using-powershell-not-executing-commands/70390452?noredirect=1#comment124481081_70390452). Just hit the next hurdle as that I can now run various 'get-az' commands with parameters but if I want to run

```
Update-AzFunctionAppSetting -ResourceGroupName "MyResourceGroup" -Name "MyFunctionApp" -SubscriptionId "MySubscriptionId" -AppSetting @{"testmw" = "2"}
```

it throws an error:
Update-AzFunctionAppSetting : Cannot index into a null array.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 0):

***Please use the below code as per your requirement :***

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features{}
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example"{
    name = "ansumantest"
}
variable "function_apps" {
  default = ["ansumanfunc1","ansumanfunc2"]
}
variable "Subscription" {
    default = "SubID"
}
resource "null_resource" "example2" {
  count = length(var.function_apps)
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<Settings
    $ResourceGroupName = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name}"
    $FunctionAppName = "${var.function_apps[count.index]}"
    $SubscriptionId = "${var.Subscription}"
    Get-AzFunctionApp -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $FunctionAppName -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId
    Update-AzFunctionAppSetting -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $FunctionAppName -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionID -AppSetting @{"testmw" = "2"}
    Settings

    interpreter = ["PowerShell", "-Command"]
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: No luck. Just using
Get-AzFunctionApp -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $FunctionAppName -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId works 
but
Update-AzFunctionAppSetting -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $FunctionAppName -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionID -AppSetting @{"testmw" = "2"}
fails with
│ Update-AzFunctionAppSetting : Cannot index into a null array.
│ At line:13 char:7
│ +       Update-AzFunctionAppSetting -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupNa ...
│ +       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: │     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Update-AzFunctionAppSetting], RuntimeException
│     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray,Update-AzFunctionAppSetting

Comment: @MWOITC, can you please add the whole updated code that you are using now ? so that  I can test the same code ..

Comment: Sure:
`code`

resource "null_resource" "az_command" {
  triggers = {
    uuid_trigger = "${uuid()}"        
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    interpreter = ["PowerShell", "-Command"]
    command = <<EOT
      $ResourceGroupName = "${module.rg.resource_group.name}"
      $FunctionAppName = "${var.function_apps.name}"
      $SubscriptionId = "${module.functionapp.function_app.id}"

Comment: `code`
      Get-AzFunctionApp -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $FunctionAppName -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId
      Update-AzFunctionAppSetting -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $FunctionAppName -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionID -AppSetting @{"testmw" = "2"}
    EOT
  }
}

Comment: @MWOITC, how are you retireving the module.functionapp.function_app.id and module.rg.resource_group.name ? are you calling this code from inside a module file?

Comment: No, main.tf calls a the function app module and the next step in main.tf is calling the 'null_resource'. Values for function app and resource group are correct as running 'Get-AzFunctionApp' returns the correct function app.

Comment: @MWOITC, ohkay so get-azfunctionapp works but update doesn't ?

Comment: Correct. get-azfunctionapp gives me the correct function app and info. The 'update' gives me the 'Cannot index into a null array' error.